# Лексикографическая сортировка без встроенных функций

Tags: php, сортировка

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, как можно отсортировать массив лексикографически, без использования встроенных функций?
В задаче вполне работает sort($array, SORT_STRING ), но было сказано писать сортировку руками, и если обычную сортировку я примерно представляю как написать, то лексикографическую - нет.
Может кто подсказать?

Comment: задача все ж навернео, сортировку реализовать, то есть метод `sort`, а не само лексикографическое сравнение строк? `strcmp` и подобное обычно для такого используется. Но если что, то и то пишется посимвольным сравнением строк, ничего сверхестественного тут нет.

Comment: @teran задача реализовать сортировку - да, но это лишь часть от общего задания, всё кроме этой части я вполне понимаю, а сортировать без функции сортировки - не умею, ибо никогда таким не занимался ( именно лексикографически), если можете привести пример - буду благодарен.

Comment: вы приведите в вопросе код и конкретику что именно вам не понятно. алгоритмов сортировки довольно много разных, самое банальное - сортировка методом пузырька, прочитайте описание и реализуйте, вложенный цикл и иф.

Comment: @teran приводить сам код не стану, но если для примера, то скажем массив чисел от 1 до 10, должен стать соответственно отсортированным лексикографически и число 10 станет перед числом 2, пузырьком вроде как только по порядку можно? или со строками оно так-же будет работать? у меня пока не особо получается понять это.

Comment: для строк вы при сравнении пишите не `a > b` а `strcmp(a,b)>0` или реализуете функцию `strcmp` самостоятельно.

Comment: @teran спасибо, вы решили мою задачу =)